# Lab Grown Organs and post surgery challenges

Tags: biology, medicine

What would be the surgical and post surgical challenges for someone who would receive a lab grown organ created specifically for them. Would they need immunosuppressants for the rest of their life or would their quality of life be lower than compared to when they had their actual organ?

Would different types of organs pose a better survivability/ compatibility rate. For example mechanical vs biological based organs.

Comment: That's kind of the point about lab-grown organs they shouldn't (in the majority of people) produce an immune reaction that needs suppressing. It's not clear what the question is here, can you narrow it down to a single issue? (And tell us how it fits into your world).

Answer (score 1):

### A More Better Situation for All!

A "lab grown" organ poses no particular supply chain or intraoperative challenges. The organ has to be prepared, packed and transported the way any donor organ has to be treated now.  Once in the OR, the organ still has to be trimmed to fit, if you will --- vessels have to be prepared for anastamosis, extraneous connective tissues have to be removed, etc. The medical transport & surgical teams will be doing the same things either way.

For the patient, the pre-operative assessments, treatments, stabilisation of disease and optimisation of surgery do not change. Just because we can grow organs in labs suitable to the individual patient, doesn't mean people won't have unstable diabetes, chronic end stage organ failure, heart disease, COPD, smoke like a chimney while on oxygen and be wheelchair bound after serial amputations. As with any surgical procedure, the risks are the same: hemorrhage, infection, cardiac arrest, unknown reaction to medications, death, and many more possibilities.

Post-operatively, the recovery should be much quicker and the result should be a much healthier patient, given the beginning circumstances. This doesn't mean a patient will be going home the same day and be training for a marathon day after surgery!

If you need an organ transplant, chances are good you're very sick. You don't usually get a new organ if you've been stabbed or shot. They just fix things up and let the body heal itself. You get an organ transplant because your organ system is horribly damaged, horribly diseased or already failed and non-functional. All this damage & illness will complicate the recovery process beyond what a healthy surgical patient will experience.

Since the organs are "lab grown", by which I will assume you mean grown from the patient's own DNA template, no immunosuppressants will be needed. It is essentially an autologous transplant, except that the organ did not grow within the patient's body.

Generally speaking a "mechanical" organ isn't "lab grown". They're completely or partially made in a factory. If there are biological components grown onto an artificial structure, that would be a hybrid.

Fully mechanical devices, like an artificial heart, are certainly possible and people have been implanted for decades. A critical replacement, like a heart, will need constant monitoring, and because of moving parts will eventually fail catastrophically. This opposed to a stable non-mechanical implant like an intraocular lens which can last indefinitely with no maintenance.

Most organs would present about the same level of post surgical difficulty. Rehabilitation, lifestyle changes, wound healing, effects of the replaced organ's disease on the rest of the body and the effects of any other diseases on the new organ will all have their effects on recovery.

**Conclusion:**  There is no one size fits all answer to your question. Generally speaking, a heart or lung transplant will pose much more serious recovery challenges than will a lab grown kidney, testicle or lens. But on the positive side, such an autologous transplant would remove a lot of other transplant related issues, meaning that it would always be the "best solution" when compared to living related donor (next best), living non-related donor (third place), cadaver donor (fourth place),  mechanical device (fifth place) and doing nothing when you have the option of any of the above (sixth place).

Comment: Gotta love the "More Better". The more the better it is, it makes it _even_ betterer ;)

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi -- Standard medical terminology!